# Drop down menu for each custom ListView item in android

Tags: android, listview, drop-down-menu

I have a custom listview, where each item contains an imageview and a textview. I want the user to be able to click on each item, and select a new combination of imageview + textview from a dropdown menu.

Here is the activity code

```
public class VisKvittering extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vis_kvittering);




    String[] data = {"Old El Paso Papadums", "Redbull 0.33L", "Colgate Max White", "Kornbrød Sammenbakt", "Laksefilet m/skinn"};

    Integer[] icons = {
            R.drawable.transpbeef,
            R.drawable.flaske,
            R.drawable.kylling2,
            R.drawable.transpbeef,
            R.drawable.transpbeef,

    };

    String[] names = {
            "Rødt kjøtt",
            "Hvitt kjøtt",
            "Fisk",
            "Meieriprodukter"

    };



    CustomList customAdapter = new CustomList(VisKvittering.this, data, icons);


    int counter = 0;
    for (String product : data){
        counter+= 1;
        if (categorizer(product) == 0) {
            icons[counter] = R.drawable.question;
            customAdapter.setFlag(counter);


        }
    }


    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(customAdapter);




}



//placeholder categorizer method
private int categorizer(String product){
    if (product.charAt(0) == 'C'){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}}
```

Here is the code for the CustomList adapter class

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] products;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomList(Activity context,
                  String[] products, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single, products);
    this.context = context;
    this.products = products;
    this.imageId = imageId;

}
int flag = -1;


@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    txtTitle.setText(products[position]);
    //int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    if (position == flag){
        txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
}

public void setFlag(int position){
    this.flag = position;
}}
```

Here is the xml for the list items

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you should have a look to simple_expandable_list_item_1 and its adapter.